# Finding an element such that the order is maximal

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question but can't find anything on lecture notes/online to help, can somebody just explain the question to me?

Find an element $\alpha \in S_{11}$ such that the order of $\alpha$ is maximal.

Comment: Take the 11 cycle. Can you have an element of order 11d where d>1? Recall that the order of c1 * .. * c_k is the lcm of length(c_i)

Comment: I have found that the order of a 5-cycle and a 6-cycle is 30 which is the maximal order but I am unable to justify why this is the case

Comment: What do you mean by maximal order?

Comment: The element within the set that has the largest order in comparison to all other elements

Comment: Ok. Thus, use the formula I gave you. You must find the maximum of L=lcm(s1,..,sk) as s_1+...+s_k=11. If the maximum of the s_i is <= 4, then L<= 4!=24. If the maximum is 5, you are left with 6. This gives at most 30 with 6=3+2+1. If the maximum is 6, you have at most 30, and if the maximum is >= 7, you have at most 7*4, 8*3,9*2,10. Thus 30 is the maximum.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you can prove the following:

Every element in $\;S_n\;$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.

A cycle has order equal to its length.

A product of disjoint cycles has order equal to the maximal common multiple of their lengths.

Thus, you already found an element of order $\;30\;$ , say $\;(1\;2\;3\;4\;5)(6\;7\;8\;9\;10\;11)\;$. You could also take $\;(1\;2)(3\;4\;5)(6\;7\;8\;9\;10))\;$

You now just to make sure there can't be a decomposition into disjoint cycles within $\;S_{11}\;$ with a higher order. Can you take it from here?